# Install Windows 11 on Boot Camp

Tags: windows, bootcamp, install, startup

Even though Macs don't meet the TPM and Secure Boot requirements of Windows 11, how can I install Windows 11 on a Mac using Boot Camp anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a sophisticated script called [MediaCreationTool.bat](https://github.com/AveYo/MediaCreationTool.bat) that upgrades a Windows 10 Boot Camp installation to Windows 11. Here are the steps to use it.

1. Install Windows 10 with Boot Camp Assistant ([Apple instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468)).
2. Stay signed into Windows 10.
3. Download the zip for [MediaCreationTool.bat](https://github.com/AveYo/MediaCreationTool.bat). (Click Code > Download ZIP.)
4. Extract the contents of the downloaded file (`MediaCreationTool.bat-main.zip`).
5. Edit the top part of `MediaCreationTool.bat` to configure the install. (E.g. if you don't want Enterprise edition, uncomment and edit the line `rem set EDITION=Enterprise`.)
6. Run `MediaCreationTool.bat` and click Windows 11 when prompted.

When Windows 11 is installing, the computer will show that it's installing Windows Server. It's not really. MediaCreationTool.bat uses tooling designed for installing Windows Server in the enterprise, but is using it to actually install Windows 11.